# Subexponential hardness assumption

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cr.crypto-security, complexity-assumptions

**Edited**
I want to read more about subexponential hardness assumption, but I didn't find any good survey on this. I just took a look at [Heavy-tailed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) and [Some properties of subexponential distributions](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02356073) but I didn't get a good picture of it.

> **Question**: What is the subexponential hardness assumption? Is it a weaker hardness assumption in comparison with discrete logarithm? Do you know any good survey or article on this?

I saw this subject in this paper:
 [Adaptive hardness and composable security in the plain model from standard assumptions](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Erafael/papers/ccacommit.pdf)

Comment: I do not think that I know the answer anyway, but can you provide more information about the term “sublinear hardness assumption”?  For example, the context where the term appears will be hopefully helpful.

Comment: I've never heard of a sublinear hardness assumption either

Comment: Sorry! My bad! Two subjects got mixed together! Please see the edited text

Comment: the reference you link to nowhere mentions "subexponential hardness assumption". It talks about subexponential hardness which I assume implies hardness of solution in subexponential time ?

Comment: @Suresh: I don't get what you mean by "the reference you link to nowhere". I have changed the topic from the original post and I think the Sadeq answer below is more to the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Complex" problems are normally defined as problems which cannot be solved by (probabilistic) polynomial-time Turing machines.

When there are extra information available for solving the problem, the model changes to machines which take advice. That is, instead of $\rm{BPP}$ machines, we consider $\rm{P/poly}$  circuits; i.e. polynomial-size circuits (equivalently, polynomial-time Turing machines which take polynomial advice).

In some cases, we may consider even stronger solvers: Instead of poly-sized circuits, we may use circuits whose size is sub-exponential. (e.g. circuits whose size is $n^{\log n}$). One might note that, an **exponential-size** family of circuits can decide any language (even undecidable ones) by merely incorporating the look-up table in its code. (In particular, the size of the look-up table is $O(n2^n)$.)

Let's consider the [Decisional Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption) (DDH) assumption.
I don't go into details. Just assume that $p$ is a large prime, all computations are over $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, and $g$ is its generator.

> **DDH:** Distinguishing $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$ from $(g,g^a,g^b,g^c)$ is hard for probabilistic polynomial-time ($\rm{PPT}$) machines.

A **stronger** assumption is:

> **DDH-1:** Distinguishing $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$ from $(g,g^a,g^b,g^c)$ is hard for $\rm{P/poly}$ circuits.

An even **stronger** assumption is:

> **DDH-2:** Distinguishing $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$ from $(g,g^a,g^b,g^c)$ is hard for sub-exponential circuits.

I saw both DDH and DDH-1 assumptions in the literature. DDH-2 may also exist, but I can't recall whether I ever saw it.

One example of *sub-exponential hardness assumption* is that, some languages in $\rm{E}$ don't have sub-exponential circuits. Such assumption is used by Impagliazzo & Wigderson in [P=BPP unless E has sub-exponential circuits:
Derandomizing the XOR Lemma](http://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IW97/proc.pdf).

---

### Description of Some Terms

While obvious, I'm going to define several terms here. Let $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a function. Then:

- $f(n) = n^{\Theta(1)}$ is called *polynomial*. (e.g. $n, n^3, 7n^{100}$.)
- $f(n) = n^{\omega(1)}$ is called *super-polynomial*. (e.g. $n^{\log n}, 2^n, 2^{2^n}$.)
- $f(n) = 2^{\Theta(n)}$ is called *linear exponential*. (e.g. $2^n, 3^n, 10^n$.)
- $f(n) = 2^{n^{\Theta(1)}}$ is called *exponential*. (e.g. $2^n, 3^{n^4}$.)
- $f(n) = 2^{n^{o(1)}}$ is called *sub-exponential*. (e.g. $2^{n^{1/n}}, n^{\log n}$.)